# Using matlab to create and graph distributions

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

How would I write the code to a six-sided dice are rolled and the two numbers showing are added to produce a sum between 2 and 12? Then plotting it

Comment: Have tried anything? If you haven't, I suggest you try it first. If you have, post whatever you have written and tell us what the difficulty is.

Answer (score 0):

This code is for 10 observation. You can change it according to your criteria.

```
for i =1:1:10
   first_no = randi([1 6],1);
   second_no = randi([1 6],1);
   if second_no == first_no
      second_no = randi([1 6],1);
   end
   sum(i) = first_no + second_no
   no(i) = 1
end
figure;
plot(no, sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define two variables that take the random values between 1-6. At the start, you can have the option of the number of observations. See the code below:

```
   no_obs = 5;
   for  i=1:no_obs
   num1 = randi([1 6],1);
   num2 = randi([1 6],1);
   sum(i) = num1 + num2;
   end
   display(sum);
   figure;
   plot(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

One roll is immediate using [`randi()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html).

```
% Assumes identical dice
Num_sides = 6;
Num_dice = 2;

% One Roll of Two Dice
Roll = randi([1 Num_sides],Num_dice,1);
Total_Pips = sum(Roll);
```

This makes it possible to write in a single line: `sum(randi([1 Num_sides],Num_dice,Num_rolls));`

```
% Many Rolls of Two Dice
Num_rolls = 1000;
Total_Pips = sum(randi([1 Num_sides],Num_dice,Num_rolls));
```

After looking at the other answers and then revisiting the question, I believe a `histogram()` would be more useful as a plot.

```
histogram(Total_Pips)
ax = gca;
ax.XTick = [2:12];
xlabel('Total Pips')
ylabel('Number of Rolls')
title([num2str(Num_rolls) ' rolls of ' num2str(Num_dice) 'x ' num2str(Num_sides) '-sided dice'])
```

[image: Histogram of the total number of pips shown after 1000 rolls of two six-sided dice.]